# Is the "wit" in "to wit" the root of any other English words?

Tags: etymology, old-english, middle-english

...and if not, where'd it go? One obvious venture is that the noun "wit", in the sense of cleverness and general know-how, has an etymological affinity with the Old English *witen*, "to know", and which Merriam-Webster informs me the "wit" in *to wit* is a conjugation of.  I can kinda-sorta see it, but the connection isn't very transparent to me.  However, I can certainly appeal to the learnèd scholars here! Are there any other surviving words *witen* bears etymological affinities to?

Comment: “witen” is actually Middle English; the Old English infinitive is “witan”.

Comment: Not exactly on topic, but: http://www.k-state.edu/english/baker/english320/Thurber-The_Owl_Who_Was_God.htm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"witness" is one.

As you already mentioned "to wit" is from an old Saxon root.  I can see some link with the German "wissen" (also to know), Dutch "weten" and (I'm told) Danish "Vide" .

As in many languages "to see" and "to know" are interrelated concepts.  So that "to wit" is not only about knowledge but witnessing.

On the knowledge side, it is also easy to see the link with *wise* and *witty* and wittingly.

The "Witan" being the Anglo Saxon assembly of wise men - knowing enough to have their word in the destiny of the community.

"wittingly": knowingly.

**update**
Following  mplungjan's comment, I read that the common root would be the Sanskrit "veda" (knowledge), which also yielded Latin "videre" (again "see" and "know").
All of these forms (including the Sanskrit) come from the [Proto-Indo-European word *weid-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_vocabulary#Mental_functions_and_states) (credits to Kosmonaut)

Comment: @Alain Pannetier Another great answer Alain -- I see you are determined to utterly crush this forum :) And I beg your pardon that it's "easy to see"; I certainly didn't recognize the "wise" connection off the top of my head.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier BTW, I hope you don't mind if I ask what you received training in? Your name sounds of French origin -- so how is it that a Frenchman comes to know so much about the English language?

Comment: @Bilare.  You're right I should update my profile... As you can see from my gravatar, I'm quite young... Just joking ;-) No I'm actually elated to have found this forum with so many like minded and learned people (whereas I get everybody in my F&F bored with etymology and languages. I just hope this will not happen again here).  I actually discovered this forum from stackoverflow and programmers.SE where I also hold other accounts.

Comment: Danish: _Vide_ ..

Comment: @Billare.  I've updated my profile.  It is now all too conspicuous that I haven't got any other literary background than that of an elder IT professional and languages hobbyist, redeemed maybe by a pathological and unquenchable curiosity.

Comment: @mplungjan.  Thanks. your comment made me curious, because "Vide" is so close to Latin "videre" (see).  So I looked it up and it turns out that the common root would be the sanscrit "veda" (kowledge !!!) so that we have now traced it back to Indo-europeans.  I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Alain :) Glad to be of service. Now I should look up the Danish "Videre" which translates to "Further"

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: The common root is not the Sanskrit word; [as you can see](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/language.gif), Indo-Iranian branched in a different direction from Germanic from the very early stages of Indo-European, so it is extremely unlikely for Sanskrit to be the root for Germanic or Italic words. All of these forms (including the Sanskrit) come from the [Proto-Indo-European word *weid-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_vocabulary#Mental_functions_and_states).

Comment: @Kosmonaut Question: Was the PIE an actual language? Perhaps I'm abusing the terminology, but to me that would be mean the PIE was spoken by a single sort of ethnic group, united by a common culture.  Did PIE speakers all live in one place, might they have wandered upon each other at some point in a long-ago time?

Comment: @Billare: Proto-Indo-European is regarded as an actual language that was spoken by the [Proto-Indo-Europeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Europeans). From Wikipedia: "Scholars estimate that PIE may have been spoken as a single language (before divergence began) around 3700 BC, though estimates by different authorities can vary by more than a millennium. The most popular hypothesis for the origin and spread of the language is the Kurgan hypothesis, which postulates an origin in the Pontic-Caspian steppe of Eastern Europe and Western Asia."

Comment: @Kosmonaut.  You're right, I can't equate Sanskrit to Indo-European.  I feel so silly, with all the books I've read dealing with the subject.  I think I need to read them again. ;-) It's a pity I'm away from my bookcase for a few weeks.  Thx for the correction.

Comment: Note also our words *idea* and *history*, which come from the same PIE root through Greek.

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: Don't worry about it. A few more weeks at EL&U and you won't be rusty anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

Witless http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/witless

Answer (score 3):

The word *wit* is from Old English. According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=wit&searchmode=none):

> "know," O.E. witan "to know," from P.Gmc. *witanan "to have seen," hence "to know" (cf. O.S. witan, O.N. vita, O.Fris. wita, M.Du., Du. weten, O.H.G. wizzan, Ger. wissen, Goth. witan "to know"); see wit (n.). The phrase **to wit**, almost the only surviving use of the verb, is first recorded 1570s, from earlier that is to wit (mid-14c.), probably a loan-translation of Anglo-Fr. cestasavoir, used to render L. videlicet (see viz.).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to ones already mentioned:

[inwit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inwit)  - mind, reason, intellect, understanding
[witcraft](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witcraft)  - logic, reasoning
[witful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inwit) — wise; sensible
[witling](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witling)- a person with little wit
[witter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witter) -  knowing, certain, sure, wis; to make sure, inform, or declare.
[witticism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witticism) - a witty remark
wittiness
[wittol](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wittol) - an acquiescent cuckold.

There are more in Middle English that I don't think are to be found in Modern English.

Comment: In addition to the above: 'nitwit', 'unwitting', 'unwittingly', and the verb 'outwit'

Answer (score 2):

The NOAD reports that *witan* (another term for *witenagemot*) derives from the Old English plural of *wita* (*wise man*).
In that case, you can say there is another word that is related to the Old English *wit*.

Comment: Both those terms (*witan* and *witenagemot*) refer to the proto-Parliament that comprised the advisory body to the king in the years before the two conquests of England in the 11th Century (the first one Danish, the second Norman). *Witenagemot* literally means "Meeting of the Wise Ones".

Comment: @Robusto Shoulda made that an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Dimwit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dimwit) is a relatively new (1920's) American construction.

> 1920-25, Americanism; dim + wit

Answer (score 0):

"Wit" in late ME also referred to any of the five senses. Probably related - "to have one's wits about one"

Comment: This is an interesting observation. Can you point readers to further information about the broad application of _wit_ to the five senses in late Middle English? That sort of amplification and documentation in an answer is much prized at this website. Without it, readers may not know how seriously to take the posted response, which unavoidably suffers from the common Internet disadvantage of coming from a total stranger of unknown expertise.

Answer (score -1):

It's prevalent in Old Norse and in modern Icelandic similarly to how it is used in modern English (notable difference = [vitki = lighthouse]).

I'd like to throw Wizard in this list. Fits contextually well with old Scandinavian mysticism
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitki